# Junit- how to test invalid usage of parameters

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit, parameters

I am supposed to write a Junit test for the invalid usage of correct parameters. I am a bit confused by this concept. Can someone please help to explain what is this scenario, and how to do this with an example?

I am testing a method that take a customer and a type of service as parameters. and I've tried the `assertFalse` method below, and tried to pass two customers to

```
assertFalse("Registration fails for add two services to one customer", cs.addPeople("Jack", "Jill","Cleaning"));
```

I realized that this is not the correct way as the `add.People()`method only takes one person as a parameter. In this case how can we test invalid usage? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't really know if I understood the problem correctly. For me it sounds a bit like a logic problem. Like your function could have one object and one service and while it's valid to have "house" and "clean" it's not valid to have "person" and "clean". Maybe you could tell a bit more about the invalid usage?

Comment: The goal (according to the requirements) is to test what happens when the user performs an invalid use of parameters, and I don't know how to test it.. I mean if the usage of the parameters is incorrect, the method wouldn't execute at all, right?

Comment: If the type of the parameter is incorrect the method would execute. But of course it could be something like (bad programming just to make the example): Method gets a string and should reaction on "A", "B" and "C", so everything else would be a invalid usage. But for that we actually would need to see the function you have to test.

Comment: I assume its talking about the state of a valid parameter. i.e. passing in the correct parameter say a Person with name Jack but a person can only be added if their name is Bob or they can perform a service etc. Otherwise they are invalid.

Comment: @cID: In that case, I would expect to test for some kind of invalid use exception (in the same way as in the answer by isah). Still, we need to know the expected behavior of the method to test it.

Comment: @Mikkel K. Without the method were in the territory of "There are known knowns"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By test invalid usage of parameters, I guess you mean write scenarios with invalid parameters.
For example.
Say that you have a method:

```
public Integer toInteger(String input){
   //conversion logic
}
```

Now, you would want to know how your method behaves on different scenarios.
One scenario would be passing invalid parameter such as `null`, and see how your method behaves.

```
@Test
public void testToIntegerForNullParam(){
   myClass.toInteger(null);
}
```

This method will not pass if you didn't handle `null` checking,  and you will have to refactor to pass this test.

```
public Integer toInteger(String input){
   if(input == null){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument was null!"); 
    }
    //conversion logic
}
```

Then in your test, you can test if this indeed throws exception when argument is null. You can use `expected = IllegalArgumentException.class`

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testToIntegerForNullParam(){
    myClass.toInteger(null);
}
```

You can continue adding more scenarios such as string not being numeric etc.

Comment: Thanks but do we not use methods like assert(...)? I didn't quite get your code.

Comment: In the above example, I was not using asserting because I was not asserting something. I was simply expecting it to throw an exception.

Comment: It says invalid usage of correct parameters. Would null be a correct parameter?

Comment: @clD the question is not properly explained. But my assumption was to test against "invalid parameters" as this is usually the case.

Comment: @user4056620 I added some more explanations.

Comment: You can use ExpectedException as well.

Comment: In the question I actually referred to a scenario like, use a valid parameter, say a customer,  and register to the same service twice. But thanks for the answer, it was quite useful